# Is there any way to change view of Django-rest-auth of login?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-auth

I've created rest APIs using Django-rest-auth, in login, it's returning key and some user info, But I need to add some status like success and message and some other things. Is there any way to override view of django-rest-auth for login?

```
class TokenSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer(many=False, read_only=True)  # this is add by myself.
    device = DeviceSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = TokenModel
        fields = ('key', 'user', 'device',)
```

Comment: which end-point of the `Django-rest-auth`  are you using?

Comment: @JPG http://127.0.0.1:8000/rest-auth/login/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Create a ***custom view class*** and use it

```
from rest_auth.views import LoginView


class CustomLoginView(LoginView):
    def get_response(self):
        orginal_response = super().get_response()
        mydata = {"message": "some message", "status": "success"}
        orginal_response.data.update(mydata)
        return orginal_response
```

and change your `urls.py` as

```
urlpatterns = [
                  url(r'custom/login/', CustomLoginView.as_view(), name='my_custom_login')

              ]
```

now you should use the endpoint **`/custom/login/`** instead of **`/rest-auth/login`**

Comment: Okay, Should I add this view in URL like this ? 
    url(r'^rest-auth/login/$', LoginView.as_view()),
and do i need change anything in settings something like we do to use cutom serializer ?
Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much. I've one question though if I do the same thing with registration, Do I need to add save function as well. As they've mentioned in their documents?(https://django-rest-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/configuration.html)
Or It can work with cutsom/registration as well. (I tried that but it's giving me the same response not updated one.)

Comment: @Kashyap I can't say how to do on registration, because we've to look into the source code to find a better way to do so

Comment: @Kashyap So, what I suggest is accept this answer if you got it worked and ask a new question in SO, that may catch more attention that this

Comment: This is the better way to do it. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65158850/how-to-create-custom-login-view-with-django-rest-auth)